# Property of the cycles of a rational map.

Tags: rational-functions, complex-dynamics

Let $C$ be the cycle of points $\{z_1,..,z_m\}$ for a rational map $R$ of degree at least $2$.  Show that either $R^{-1}(C)$ contains pre-periodic points or $C$ is completely invariant, has two elements, and lies in the Fatou set.

I'm stuck trying to pull a few ideas together to prove this.  Here are some facts that I have so far:

- $C$ is finite.  I'm not sure how to show invariance.  However, if I
  can show $C$ is invariant, then the following is true:  for some $n$ 
  we have that $R^n(C)=C$.  Suppose that $R^n$ has degree $d$.  Then by
  Riemann-Hurwitz we have $k(d-1)\leq 2d-2$.
- $R^{-1}(C)=C$ in only a few circumstance.  But, if it doesn't, it's because of pre-periodic points.  In particular, $|R^{-1}(C)|<=n|C|$.

My attempt at a proof:  Since $C$ has a finite orbit we know it's an invariant set.  Since $R$ is a rational map and $C$ is completely invariant, then by the first bullet point we know that it has at most two elements.  Furthermore, $C$ is a set of exceptional points, so it lives in the Fatou set.

I'm not sure if this is correct.  Nor am I sure how the problem changes with the introduction of pre-periodic points.